# There is no method "Filereader" in class

Tags: java

Could you help me understand why I get this message:

```
There is no method Filereader` in class...
```

I transferred a file into the `readFile()` method. It is visible in the picture that the file has been transferred correctly. Then I'm trying to create a `FileReader` instance. 
In java-doc I can the constructor scheme:

```
public FileReader(File file).
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work?

[image]

Comment: Did you import `java.io.FileReader`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman He must have if line 81 isn't an error.

Comment: Off topic but why is your `FileReader` variable named `inputStream`?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace that is being thrown?

Comment: @RaulRene looks like compiler error, so there's no stacktrace.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It looks to me like he's debugging

Comment: I suspect you have imported a different FileReader class to the one you have Javadocs for. What is the full name of the FileReader class you wish to use?

Comment: It attempts to locate the method `FileReader(File file)` in the `parallelprogramming.HotThrd` class and not in the `java.io.FileReader` class. There should be a collision between packages.

Comment: If the compiler couldn't find the method, it would never have compiled the code, hence we wouldn't be in the middle of a debugging session. Therefore I'm pretty certain the code is fine, and the debugger is just confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest it's just a problem with the NetBeans debugger. The fact that you have watched variables down the bottom, and what looks like a 'current line' means that there is nothing wrong with the code.

Rather, it looks like the debugger is trying to be helpful by giving you information, but is not smart enough to tell the difference between a localised function call and asking for an object from an import.

If it runs, and that seems to be the case, simply note the ineptitude of the NetBeans developers and ignore the message.